# How do I increase memory heap size in electron 22?

Tags: electron

How do I increase memory heap size in electron 22?
**electron version:22.1.0**

I use `app.commandLine.appendSwitch('js-flags', '--max-old-space-size=8192');`. it does not seem to work.

and it work when the size is less then `4096`.
Is there any other solution?

Comment: maybe relevant: https://www.electronjs.org/blog/v8-memory-cage